Is it expected to have a epsilon-named attribute of a python object turned into varepsilon silently?
If I create an attribute named ϵ for a Python object using a dot expression, the name is converted to ε without any warning.
Is this expected? If it is, where can I find a reference about this?
Python 3.12.5 (main, Aug  7 2024, 13:49:14) [GCC 14.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = type('',(),{})()
>>> a.ϵ = 100
>>> hasattr(a,'ϵ')
False
>>> hasattr(a,'ε')
True
>>> setattr(a,'ϵ',200)
>>> hasattr(a,'ϵ')
True
>>> a.ϵ
100
>>> 


Those two are the same identifier in normal form NFKC.
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", 'ε') == unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", 'ϵ')
True

And as the docs say,

All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC while parsing; comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.

So – yes, it's expected.
